# Perl Hash + File + While

Tags: perl

well, the idea is to remove a file a direction with their description and store it in a hash

this is content in file /home/opmeitle/files-pl/bookmarks2

```
    }, {
       "date_added": "12989744094664781",
       "id": "1721",
       "name": "Perl DBI - dbi.perl.org",
       "type": "url",
       "url": "http://dbi.perl.org/"
    }, {
       "date_added": "12989744373130384",
       "id": "1722",
       "name": "DBD::mysql - MySQL driver for the Perl5 Database Interface (DBI) - metacpan.org",
       "type": "url",
       "url": "https://metacpan.org/module/DBD::mysql"
    }, {
```

now, the code in perl.

```
use strict;

open(FILE, '/home/opmeitle/files-pl/bookmarks2');  
my @lines = <FILE>;
my @list55;
my $count = 1;
my $n = 0;
my %hash=();   #$hash{$lines[$n]}=$lines[$n];
    while ($lines[$n]) {
        if ($lines[$n] =~ /(http:|https:|name)/) {
            if ($lines[$n] =~ s/("|: |,|id|url|name|\n)//g) {
                if ($lines[$n] =~ s/^\s+//){
                    if ($lines[$n] =~ /http:|https/){ 
                        $hash{$lines[$n]} = '';
                    }
                    else {
                        $hash{$n} = $lines[$n];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    $n++;
    $count++;
    }
close(FILE);
# print hash
my $key;
my $value;
while( ($key,$value) = each %hash){
    print "$key = $value\n";
}
```

result after executing the script.

```
http://dbi.perl.org/ = 
https://metacpan.org/module/DBD::mysql = 
3 = Perl DBI - dbi.perl.org
9 = DBD::mysql - MySQL driver for the Perl5 Database Interface (DBI) - metacpan.org
```

but i need something like this

```
http://dbi.perl.org/ = Perl DBI - dbi.perl.org
Perl DBI - dbi.perl.org = DBD::mysql - MySQL driver for the Perl5 Database Interface (DBI) - metacpan.org
```

thanks for you answers.

Comment: use pragma `strict`, save your life :)

Comment: is an file where save bookmarks in chrome

Comment: is the expected result you show correct. It seems that it should be "url" = "name" but the second line doesn't follow that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @amon hinted, Chrome bookmarks are JSON format, for which there are several good modules on [CPAN](https://metacpan.org/search?q=json).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON;

my $file = '/home/opmeitle/files-pl/bookmarks2';
open my $fh, '<', $file or die "$file: $!\n";
my $inhash = decode_json(join '', <$fh>);
close $fh;

my %outhash = map traverse($_), values %{ $inhash->{roots} };
sub traverse
{
  my $hashref = shift;

  if (exists $hashref->{children}) {
    return map traverse($_), @{ $hashref->{children} };
  } else {
    return $hashref->{url} => $hashref->{name};
  }
}
```

Now `%outhash` has the data you wanted.

EDIT: to help understand what's going on here:

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper($inhash); # pretty-print the structure returned by decode_json
```

Comment: I think using a global for this is really odd. Simply collecting the returns should be good enough.

Comment: @JoelBerger good point, just realised I can use `map` for that, edited

Comment: much better, I'm still not quite sure what the OP wants the traversal to do, but whatever it is, this is much nicer now. :-)

Comment: Thank you for everything I could troubleshoot the script, i would have liked an explanation of each line to then be able to implement it without haste from already thanks

Comment: @opmeitle `decode_json` returns a hash of hashes of arrays of hashes of arrays of hashes up to an arbitrary level of nesting (because that's the format of the bookmarks file). `traverse` is a recursive subroutine that goes through the hash collecting url/name pairs. Also see my edit.

Comment: I already understood, moreover i could save all through a loop to mysql, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, the best thing to do is to load the JSON data into a Perl datastructure. This is easily done using the [`JSON`](http://p3rl.org/JSON) module. Before we can do this, we need to read in the file. There are two ways to do this. The non-CPAN way:

```
# always ...
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = '/home/opmeitle/files-pl/bookmarks2';

my $text = do {
  open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Cannot open $file: $!\n";
  local $/; #enable slurp
  <$fh>;
};
```

or the CPAN way

```
# always ...
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Slurp;
my $text = read_file $file;
```

Once you have the file read in, then decode

```
use JSON;

my $data = decode_json $text;
```

Please post a whole file and a better description of what you want and I would be glad to comment on a more formal way of traversing the datastructure.

Comment: The archive is used by chrome to save bookmarks in any way serves to any json, thank you very much for your help i was served, although i would have needed a detail of each line of code

Comment: `i would have needed a detail of each line of code` The purpose of SO is not to teach you Perl, but to help you through problem points in your code. If you need a line by line description of its syntax (more than I have already given) I recommend starting by reading [The Modern Perl Book](http://onyxneon.com/books/modern_perl/index.html) which is a free PDF download.